# mixing CRTP with SFINAE

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, sfinae, crtp

I have a `base` taking derived type as template parameter. The following code works as expected. instantiation of `base<non_default_impl>` uses `non_default_impl::data_t` and `base<default_impl>` throws compilation error because `event_data` is only a forward declaration.

```
template <typename T>
struct event_data;

template<typename T>
struct tovoid {
    typedef void type;
};

template <typename T, typename enable = void>
struct get_data{
  typedef event_data<T> type;
};

template <typename T>
struct get_data<T, typename tovoid<typename T::data_t>::type >{
  typedef typename T::data_t type;
};

template <typename T>
struct base{
    typedef typename get_data<T>::type data_type;

    base(){
        data_type();
    }
};

struct non_default_impl{
    struct data{};

    typedef data data_t;
};
struct default_impl{

};

int main(){
    base<non_default_impl> e1;
    base<default_impl> e2;
    return 0;
}
```

But when `non_default_impl` inherits from `base<non_default_impl>` SFINAE substitutes to the forward declaration.

```
struct non_default_impl: public base<non_default_impl>{
    struct data{};

    typedef data data_t;
};

int main(){
    non_default_impl e1;
//  base<default_impl> e2;
    return 0;
}
```

> prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'base::base() [with T =
>   non_default_impl]':
>
> prog.cpp:28:8:   required from here
>
> prog.cpp:24:3: error: invalid use of incomplete type 
>   'base::data_type {aka struct
>   event_data}'    data_type();

How to make this work. I want if the derived class have a `data_t` typedef use that otherwise use `event_data<derived_type>`

https://ideone.com/WOIsn0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a caveat of CRTP : at the time your `base` template is specialized for your `non_default_impl` class, i.e in its base classes list, `non_default_impl` itself is not defined yet.

Thus, any attempt to access anything that is part of its definition, for example the `data_t` typedef, fails.

Since you cannot use anything that is inside `non_default_impl`, a solution is to use an external type trait to choose your `data_t` :

```
template <class T>
struct dataType { typedef event_data<T> type; };

template <typename T>
struct base{
    typedef typename dataType<T>::type data_type;

    // ...
};

// Usage

struct non_default_data {};

template <>
struct dataType<struct non_default_impl> {
    typedef non_default_data type;
};

struct non_default_impl: public base<non_default_impl> {
    // ...
};
```

Note that you can't declare `non_default_data` inside `non_default_impl`, since it must be accessible from the type trait, which must be accessible from the CRTP, which still has to be specialized before `non_default_impl` is defined.