# How to infer the type in CRTP?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crtp

I want to implement CRTP in c++ template. The code is as below:

```
template <typename T>
class A{
public:
    typedef typename T::Scalar Scalar;
};
template <typename T>
struct B:public A<B<T> > {
public:
    typedef T Scalar;
};
```

But when I [compile the code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74501e45f5596898) the compiler shows:

```
error: no type named ‘Scalar’ in ‘struct B<int>’
```

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290887/mixing-crtp-with-sfinae), but this question is much clearer so I think we should reverse-dupe-close the other one once this has an answer.

Comment: @Quentin Have any idea about this?

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36291020/3233393) to that linked question fits this one as well (`B` is incomplete when you instantiate `A<B>`), but I feel copy/patching/pasting my answer here would be cheap.

Comment: @Quentin So, I have to add a traits?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the API for `A<T>` says that `T::Scalar` must be defined, which isn't yet the case in `template<typename U> struct B:public A<B<U> > {`.

The simple change is to fix the API of A:

```
template <typename SCALAR>
class A{
public:
    typedef SCALAR Scalar;
};
template <typename T>
struct B:public A<T> {
};
```

In abstract terms, the use of `A<T>, T::Scalar` is a form of pass-by-name, whereas `A<SCALAR>` is regular pass-by-argument. And pass-by-name is problematic when the names aren't yet defined at the point where you need them.

[edit]
And because it appears to be non-obvious, you can still keep the CRTP:

```
template <typename SCALAR, typename CRTP>
class A{
public:
    typedef SCALAR Scalar;
};
template <typename T>
struct B:public A<T, B<T>> {
};
```

Comment: But here `A` doesn't have any information of `B` at all. How can `A<T>` use any method of `B<T>` now? The CRTP is gone!

Comment: @iammilind: Well, you can keep the CRTP and _still_ pass `SCALAR` separately. The two aren't mutually exclusive. CRTP just was not needed for `B::Scalar`.

Comment: Probably you are assuming that, in this case CRTP is used only to get `Scalar` only; right? But what if CRTP & `Scalar` both are required for different purposes? From the Q, it seems that OP wants CRTP and on the other side he/she is stumbled upon the internal `typedef` of `Scalar`.

Comment: @iammilind: `T::Scalar` isn't an internal typedef in the question, it's a pass-by-name argument to `A<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to incomplete type. Look at below line:

```
template<typename T>
struct B : public A<B<T>>
```

The body of `B<T>` is yet to start and you are using it as a parameter in building `A<T>`. Actually this is allowed, but as mentioned in [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36291020/514235), it's a caveat of CRTP. Apart from that answer, here is another way:

```
template <template<typename> class Base, typename T>
class A{ // use `<typename...>` for C++11
public:  
  typedef T Scalar;
  // use `Base<T>` wherever required
};

template <typename T>
struct B : public A<B, T> {
public: //        ^^^^^^^
    typedef T Scalar;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it,

```
B<int> b is called which will invoke
B<int> : A<B<int> > which will further invoke // B is not yet done waiting on A<B<int> >

A<B<int>> { typedef B<int>::Scalar Scalar } will try to fetch B<int> //which is not yet constructed as many pointed out.
```

Below code is not the solution but will explain what is the problem. Below code compiles because we broke the loop.

```
template <typename T>
class A{
public:
    typedef typename T::Scalar Scalar;
};

template <typename T>
class B:public A<B<T> > {
public:
    typedef T Scalar;
};

template <>
class A<B<int> > {
public :
        typedef int Scalar;
};

int main()
{
        B<int> b;
}
```

Now the solution is to break the loop or avoid the loop. We can think of few solutions accordingly.